# How validate geofencing location to current location in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I fetch the user current location data.But the problem is I can't create proper geofencing . After geofencing  validate current location with some static lat long radius .

```
import UIKit 
import MapKit 
import CoreLocation 
import UserNotifications


class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let manager = CLLocationManager()
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
var locality = ""
var administrativeArea = ""
var country = ""
var totalAdress:String?
var maplatitude:String?
var maplognitude:String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // Your coordinates go here (lat, lon)
    let geofenceRegionCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 37.33233141,
        longitude: -122.0312186
    )

    let geofenceRegion = CLCircularRegion(
        center: geofenceRegionCenter,
        radius: 100,
        identifier: "UniqueIdentifier"
    )

    geofenceRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
    geofenceRegion.notifyOnExit = true

    self.manager.startMonitoring(for: geofenceRegion)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myLocation, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    // manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    // print(location.altitude)
    // print(location.speed)
    // maplatitude = location.altitude

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    var locationArray = locations as NSArray
    var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
    var coord = locationObj.coordinate
    maplatitude = String(coord.longitude)
    maplognitude = String(coord.latitude)

    // longitude.text = coord.longitude
    // latitude.text = coord.latitude
    // longitude.text = "\(coord.longitude)"
    // latitude.text = "\(coord.latitude)"

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    print("Latitude is ",coord.latitude)
    print("Lognitude is ",coord.longitude)

    // maplatitude = String(coord.longitude)
    // maplognitude = String(coord.latitude)


    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error in reverseGeocode")
        }

        let placemark = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
        if placemark.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            self.locality = placemark.locality!.removeWhitespace()
            self.administrativeArea = placemark.administrativeArea!.removeWhitespace()
            self.country = placemark.country!.removeWhitespace()
            self.totalAdress = self.locality + "," + self.administrativeArea + "," + self.country
            print("mylocality",self.locality)
            print("country",self.country)
            print("myLocality",self.totalAdress)

            //self.adressNAmeLabel.text = self.totalAdress
        }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: can you explain in more details what is the problem here?

Comment: Actually I  am trying to validation in geofencing in current location.when user in location that time notification User in area and when user exit specify location that time alert your now out.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use notifications for this

```
                let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLatitude, myLongtitude)
                let region = CLCircularRegion(center: location, radius: radius, identifier: "my-custom-uuid")
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "Title"
                content.body = "Body"
                content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                region.notifyOnEntry = true
                region.notifyOnExit = false
                let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: false)
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:"uuid", content: content, trigger: trigger)
                self.center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

This is a link to one tutorial [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250)

And also you should have in mind that you will need location authorization(the good point here is that you need just in-app not in background) and you can register up to 20 points.